# Assigning an object from an interface instance to another interface instance

Tags: java

MyInt.java:

```
interface Outer{
   void ofoo();
   interface Inner {
      void ifoo();
   }
}
```

MyClass.java:

```
class MyInfClass implements Outer, Outer.Inner{
   int x;
   public void ofoo{
      // 
   }
   public void ifoo{
      // 
   }
}

class MyClass{
   void testFoo(){
       Outer obj = new MyInfClass();
       Inner iObj;
       //iObj = obj; Tried this and got compilation error
//Out of wild guess I tried the following
       iObj = (MyInfClass) obj; //Runs Successfully
       iObj.ifoo();
   }
}
```

Is this behaviors defined and is it applicable to other scenarios like

```
Interface interfaceRef = new SubClass(); // SubClass implements the Interface
SuperClass superClassRef = (SubClass) interfaceRef;
```

Is there any other proper way to do this?

Comment: When creating an object, best thing to do is use the class name. There is no need for type-checking and casting around: you know what type that object is. You created it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution is to use the more general `interface` only when it does not break other code. In your case using the `Outer` interface breaks things so use the actual class.

```
interface Outer {

    void ofoo();

    interface Inner {

        void ifoo();
    }
}

class MyInfClass implements Outer, Outer.Inner {

    int x;

    @Override
    public void ofoo() {
        //
    }

    @Override
    public void ifoo() {
        //
    }
}

public void test() {
   MyInfClass mic = new MyInfClass();
   Outer obj = mic;
   Outer.Inner iObj = mic;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
iObj = obj;
```

doesn't pass compilation because `Outer` is not a sub-interface of `Inner`.

```
iObj = (MyInfClass) obj;
```

passes compilation because `MyInfClass` implements `Inner`, so a `MyInfClass` reference can be safely assigned to an `Inner` variable.

However, the safest way to make such an assignment is to test the type of `obj` before the casting:

```
if (obj instanceof Inner)
    iobj = (Inner) obj;
```

Comment: Is this can be applied to similar scenarios?

Comment: Like this `Interface interfaceRef = new SubClass(); // SubClass implements the Interface
SuperClass superClassRef = (SubClass) interfaceRef;`

Comment: @Sab yes, you can do it, but you should always test the type using `instanceof` before doing such type casts.